# rosrun cannot find executables under turtlesim

Tags: ros, turtlesim, raspberrypi, rosrun, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this question has been asked many times, but I really wanted to understand what was wrong with my commands and environment setup. I tried solutions from other sources but none worked in my case.

I installed ROS indigo on Raspberry Pi 3 following this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

And I am going through beginner tutorials, currently on section "Understanding ROS Nodes" with following link: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes

As I ran command `rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node`, the terminal gave following output error: `[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named turtlesim_node below /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_tutorials/turtlesim`

I have added `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash; source ~/ros_catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash;`in the end of `~/.bashrc` file.

Also, my working space is `ros_catkin_ws`.

As I run `rospack profile`, it produces following output:

0.065189   /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src

0.029168 * /opt/ros/indigo/share

0.020896   /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm

0.008227   /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_control

0.005578   /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros

0.003114   /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/roscpp_core

0.002664   /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/joystick_drivers

0.002548   /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/common_msgs

0.002168   /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_tutorials

0.001130   /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/diagnostics

0.000709   /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm_msgs

As I run `rospack find turtlesim`, it successfully find location of the package at `/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_tutorials/turtlesim`

So can someone give me detailed instructions on how to follow the tutorial and find the executables? Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232873/rosrun-cannot-find-executables-under-turtlesim/) by [GarethZhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26435/garethzhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The location of the turtlesim package is in the dir. opt/ros/indigo/share, you can search turtlesim_node in your catkin workspace to make sure where there is a executable or not.

---

Originally posted by [langqy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26159/langqy/) with karma: 16 on 2016-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0